# Trouble parsing HTML page with Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to get a hold of the data under the columns having the code "SEVNYXX", where "XX" are the numbers that follow (eg. 01, 02, etc) on the site http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html using Python. I am currently using the following method as prescribed by the site http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/ . However, I don't know how to determine the `div`s for this page and am hence unable to proceed and was hoping to get some help with this.

This is what I have so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Thank You

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry, just added that.

Comment: Does it need to be python? It seems the page is static, and if you simply copy/paste the table to a spread sheet, you can easily extract the columns manually. That might be easier. Processing HTML with xpath is not the easiest thing to conquer.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Thank You. However, if the page is updated can't I then  simply re-download the data through my code? Is there an easier way to process HTML than using xpath?

Comment: If it is indeed dynamic then you do need some kind of scripting :) BeautifulSoup would have been my next recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? I'm a pretty big fan. Using that you can easily iterate through all of the info you want, searching by tag.

Here's something I threw together, that prints out the values in each column you are looking at. Not sure what you want to do with the data, but hopefully it helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

page = request.urlopen('http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[2]

# Find the columns you want data from
headers = desired_table.findAll('th')
desired_columns = []
for th in headers:
    if 'SVENY' in th.string:
        desired_columns.append(headers.index(th))

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    cells= row.findAll('td')
    for column in desired_columns:
        print(cells[column].text)
```

In response to your second request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

page = request.urlopen('http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
data = {}

# Find the columns you want data from
headers = desired_table.findAll('th')
desired_columns = []
column_count = 0
for th in headers:
    if 'SVENY' in th.string:
        data[th.string] = {'column': headers.index(th), 'data': []}
        column_count += 1

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    date = row.findAll('th')[0].text
    cells= row.findAll('td')

    for header,info in data.items():
        column_number = info['column']
        cell_data = [date,cells[column_number].text]
        info['data'].append(cell_data)
```

This returns a dictionary where each key is the header for a column, and each value is another dictionary that has 1) the column it's in on the site, and 2) the actual data you want, in a list of lists.

As an example:

```
for year_number in data['SVENY01']['data']:
    print(year_number)

['2015-06-05', '0.3487']
['2015-06-04', '0.3124']
['2015-06-03', '0.3238']
['2015-06-02', '0.3040']
['2015-06-01', '0.3009']
['2015-05-29', '0.2957']
etc.
```

You can fiddle around with this to get the info how and where you want it, but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: This is great! However, do you know how I could include the header and row Titles to these? And, also include all the rows?

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, I get an error in the line `date = row.findAll('th')[0].text`, which is `IndexError: list index out of range`. I am using Python 2.7 though and am hence using `import urllib2                   content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)` instead of using `request`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. All that `date` line is doing is, for the row of the table it's on, pulling the data from the th tag, like this one on the site: `<th scope="row">2015-06-05</th>` The index out of range error implies to me that `row.findAll(th')` is returning an empty list, which is strange. Does this occur on the first iteration?

Comment: If you continue to have the problem, I'd suggest making a new question for it with more info, since I think it would constitute as a separate issue.